# Core Text: Drop caps + paragraph styles: Incompatible?

Tags: ios, core-text

I'm attempting to draw a richly laid out text view on iPhone that features:

1. Custom paragraph spacing (`kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierParagraphSpacing`)
2. Custom paragraph first-line indentation (`kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierFirstLineHeadIndent`)
3. Justified alignment (`kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierAlignment`)
4. **Finally, a [drop cap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial) on my first paragraph**

I'm using [`OHAttributedLabel`](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel). The first three points I achieved without much trouble by just setting some paragraph style attributes on my `NSAttributedString`.

The drop cap I managed to implement by hacking `OHAttributedLabel`:

1. Cut out a rectangular region out of the main paragraph's `CGMutablePathRef` the size of the drop cap by adding an extra `CGPathAddRect`, as detailed in [this excellent blog post](http://amyworrall.com/post/11098565269/text-wrap-with-core-text).
2. Drawing the large character in this region with an extra `CTFrameDraw` call.

**My problem:** The paragraph styles and the custom text path are incompatible. When I cut a rectangular chunk out of the main text's path, **all the paragraph styles seem to get thrown away**.

Does anyone know a way to make them work together? Or can anyone think of another way to implement drop caps? (Short of using a `UIWebView` + CSS, which I'd rather not have the overhead of!)

Thanks!

Comment: It would be great to see some code for how you implement the dropcap with the nsattributed string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use straight Core Text to achieve this, in the following post I explain the use of 2 framesetters to lay out text with drop caps in a UIView. In the code example (there's also a link to a github repo) you'll be able to see where the paragraph styles are created and applied to the main text view.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14639864/1218605