# Indenting UIlabel around another UILabel (Drop Capping)

Tags: swift3, uilabel, core-text

I would like to produce this effect:

[image: labels]

The number is a `UILabel` and the words are a `UILabel`. I can't separate the text into two `UILabel`'s. The first two lines of the words `UILabel` should match up with the number `UILabel`, then the third line (etc..) should be below the number `UILabel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you seem to be looking for is CoreText. See the following answer:

[Drop cap with NSAttributedString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214900/drop-cap-with-nsattributedstring)