# UILabel or UITextView with first letter very big font in two line

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uilabel, uitextview

How to customize UILabel or UITextView like given image i-e big "T" is shown in two lines of the label. Or please suggest any library for that:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will find in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214900/drop-cap-with-nsattributedstring) a lot of useful informations about this topic

So you need use CoreText to achieve your goal.

Comment: Unfortunately the github example in this link is incomplete. But I guess I got a direction to achieve it, for that i need to learn some core concepts of CoreText framework. Can you send me a working example if you already have experience with CoreText framework ? Thanks

Comment: unfortunately I don't have great knowledge about CoreText. But I think that you can check how other use it, here you have bunch of open source projects: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=coretext

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Note this only for TextView**

```
        NSString *myTextString =@"Your are qualified as a lawyer specializing in marine cases, shipping, arbitration and commercial litigation";
        UIBezierPath * imgRect = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)]; // you can change this as per your needs
        txtViewDescription.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[imgRect];
        txtViewDescription.text =  myTextString;
        txtViewDescription.text = [txtViewDescription.text substringFromIndex:1]; // Remove first letter from string

        UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 80, 80)];// you can change this as per your needs
        lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:Lato_BOLD size:50];
        lbl.text = [myTextString substringToIndex: 1]; // get first letter of string
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:lbl];
        [self.view addSubview:lbl];// if your textview added to self.view else change with your view
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I implemented on a playground (**Swift 3 answer**):

```
import UIKit

// declare the label:
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
label.numberOfLines = 2
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

// this should be the desired text
let myString = "This is my pretty string that should contains a couple of lines."

// setup the attributed string
let content = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)])
content.setAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 1))

// assign the string to the label
label.attributedText = content
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@KKRocks's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44647793/1748956) in `Swift 3.0`

```
    let yourString = "This easy granola is inspired by a grain-free granola from Costco that I love. The ingredient list is short so I figured that I could make it at home quite easily."



    let lbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 5, width: 30, height: 30))
    lbl.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 40)
    lbl.text = yourString[0]
    txtView.addSubview(lbl)
    txtView.bringSubview(toFront: lbl)

    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 35, height: 30))
    txtView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = [bezierPath]
    txtView.text = yourString.substring(from: 1)
    // txtView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)
```